# van Wijngaarden transformation resources

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods

[Wikipedia's treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Wijngaarden_transformation) is superficial, with only the original Dutch paper as a reference. I'm interested in resources with more detailed discussion of the transformation. In particular I hope to learn how rapidly the transformation converges (the answer will presumably depend on how rapidly the original series converges), or why the stop-two-thirds-of-the-way trick works.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks; fixed.

Comment: There is a section Accelerating the Convergence of Series in Press et al, Numerical recipes, see e.g. http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/linearalgebra/NumericalRecipiesInC/c5-1.pdf or in Aksenov et al
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0207086v1, where the Van Wijngaarden transformation is used to compute the Lerch transcendent $\Phi$.

Comment: Here are two other more detailed papers:

van Wijngaarden, A. (1953). A transformation of formal series,
https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/9276/9276A.pdf
   and 
Lauwerier, H.A. (1972). A note on the van wijngaarden transformation,
https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/7719/7719A.pdf

Answer (score 3):

A bit too large for a comment. [This](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/exp-math-9/fulltext.pdf) paper by Cohen, Villegas, and Zagier, is a nice reference. Although they introduce their own variation on the method, the exposition also covers convergence for the Euler and Euler-Van Wijngaarden methods, which they show are all part of a family of methods. See in particular Proposition 1 and the remarks that follow it.

For the Euler method (and a particular class of sequences) you get an error of $2^{-d}$ with $d$ summands, while for the Euler-Van Wijngaarden method this is improved to $3^{-d}$.

The paper also, implicitly, explains where the “stop at two thirds” comes from. All these methods are based on a polynomial approximation of $(1+x)^{-1}$ on the interval $[0,1]$. The Taylor expansion at $x=0$ results simply in the partial sums as approximation. The Taylor expansion at $x=1$ leads to the Euler method. Note that in this case the maximum error of the polynomial approximation is $2^{-d}$ at $x=0$.

The Van Wijngaarden trick is to use a polynomial that agrees to order $d_1$ at $x=0$ and to degree $d_2$ at $x=1$, where $d = d_1 + d_2$ is the total degree. It turns out that the maximal error over $[0,1]$ is minimized for $d_1$ and $d_2$ close to $d/3$ and $2d/3$ respectively.

Finally, the method proposed in the linked paper proposes an approximation based on Chebyshev polynomials to achieve a near optimal maximal error.